# Which bean can be termed highest in terms of performance?

Tags: ejb-3.0

Stateful Session bean,MDB,CMP or BMP??

Though I am not sure how we can compare the performance against each other, I would like to know which is best in performance

Comment: If you don't know how to compare the performance why do you know which one is the best? And what 'the best' would mean anyway to you?

Comment: I meant fastest in terms of performance piotr. just for the sake of improving knowledge

Comment: Ok, but how do you want to compare it? Also please describe your question better - at this point you want to compare "Message Driven Bean" with "Container Managed Persistence" and "Bean Managed Persistence". It's like comparing JMS messages receive speed to speed of persisting object in the database...

Comment: Once again - do you want to compare container vs bean **persistence** management or do you want to compare different EJB bean types: MDB, SLSB and SFSB? Define exactly **what** do you want to compare.

Comment: dont want to compare persistance management....just different entity types...:)

Comment: What **entity types** are you referring to? Old EJB 2.0 EJB Entities vs JPA Entities?

Comment: JPA entities are the same regardless where they are used - in MDB, SLSB or SFSB. CMP and BMP are not relevant for JPA as these are from EJB 2.x era. You cannot compare SFSB and MDB with CMP and BMP.